# Oracle SQL result in multiple columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a SQL query of a single column that places the output in multiple rows.  For instance:

```
Select distinct academic_year from AFF_EVENT_V
Order by academic_year;
```

This results in the following:

```
2002-2003
2003-2004
2004-2005
2005-2006
2006-2007
2007-2008
2008-2009
2009-2010
2010-2011
2011-2012
2012-2013
2013-2014
2014-2015
2015-2016
2016-2017
2017-2018
```

I'd like the results to appear in multiple (let's say 5) "columns".
I'm looking for results something like this:

```
2002-2003     2003-2004     2004-2005     2005-2006     2006-2007
2007-2008     2008-2009     2009-2010     2010-2011     2011-2012
etc.
```

How can I structure a Query to result in this output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when mod(seqnum, 5) = 0 then academic_year end),
       max(case when mod(seqnum, 5) = 1 then academic_year end),
       max(case when mod(seqnum, 5) = 2 then academic_year end),
       max(case when mod(seqnum, 5) = 3 then academic_year end),
       max(case when mod(seqnum, 5) = 4 then academic_year end)
from (select academic_year, row_number() over (order by academic_year) - 1 as seqnum
      from AFF_EVENT_V
      group by academic_year
     ) a
group by floor(seqnum / 5);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  That gave exactly the response I was looking for in SQL Developer.  Do you happen to know much about Oracle Apex?  When I put your suggestion as the SQL for a report I get an error in Apex 5: Column name "MAX(CASEWHENMOD(SEQNUM,5)=0THENACADEMIC_YEAREND)" is invalid for the SQL query. Make sure that you use unique alias names for your columns.

Comment: Just create an alias for each of those "MAX" values, such as "dummy" value_1, value_2, ..., value_5

Comment: Yup.  Realized that as soon as I pressed the button.  :-)  I just added "C1" and "C2" after the last parenthesis of each line.  Thanks again.  I appreciate it!